# How many different ways are there to pay exactly $20$ p using only $1$ p and $2$ p?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many different ways are there to pay exactly $20$ p using only $1$ p and $2$ p?

Any quicker method to solve such type of questions? tried writing a list of numbers but I don't think it is a suitable workout for an exam.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:permutations].  Does the order of the coins matter in the counting?  For instance, if I pay 5 2p coins and 10 1p coins, is that the same as or different than paying 3 2p coins, 10 1p coins, then 2 more 2p coins?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume that the order of the coins doesn't affect the count.  In other words, "5 2p coins and 10 1p coins" and "3 2p coins, 10 1p coins, and 2 more 2p coins" are counted the same.

If so, you can have any number of 2p coins between 0 and 10.  For each of those, there's a unique way to add in 1p coins so that the total value will be 20p.